# Serilog logging to Azure Blob Table problem. Removed the logging code but an errant process is still writing every 5 minutes, two days later

Tags: c#, azure, serilog

I have a .Net 6.0 MVC project which i upgraded from 2.1. At the same time i thought that i would change the logging from disk to Azure Table Storage. So during testing all was well. Then after production all was well. Then 3 days ago some weird repetitive logging started. The error message referred to a serialization error - that had never happened in the 4 months of dev period. The offending property was deprecated so i removed it and deployed to production. But the logs are still continuing. Has anyone had any experience of this rogue behaviour?